# Why is Tkinter Toplevel object being destroyed?

Tags: python, tkinter

In the code below, `tk` is not the parent of the `Toplevel` object that is created by the function `launch()`.  However, when I destroy `tk` using `tk.destroy()`, the Toplevel window vanishes.

Is the Toplevel widow being destroyed? If so, how is `Toplevel.destroy()` being called?

```
from tkinter import *


def launch():
    Toplevel()

tk = Tk()

frame = Frame(tk, relief="ridge", borderwidth=2)
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
label = Label(frame, text="Hello, World")
label.pack(fill=X, expand=1)

button1 = Button(frame, text="Exit", command=tk.destroy)
button2 = Button(frame, text="Launch", command=launch)

button1.pack(side="bottom")
button2.pack(side="bottom")

tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What keeps your application running is the mainloop of the `Tk` instance, which is the parent of all widgets. When you destroy it, all the widgets are also destroyed.

---

Keeping in mind that for each Tk instance, there's an associated *Tcl* interpreter, I will try to give a more detailed answer on what happens when you close a window, based on the docs strings of the Tk and associated classes and methods of the *tkinter* module.

Tk derives from 2 classes: *Misc* and *Wm*. In the Misc class, you can find the interface and the documentation for the *quit* method:

```
def quit(self):
    """Quit the Tcl interpreter. All widgets will be destroyed."""
    self.tk.quit()
```

You can find under the `destroy` method of the Tk class the following:

```
def destroy(self):
    """Destroy this and all descendants widgets. This will
    end the application of this Tcl interpreter."""
```

The *destroy* method in the *Tk* class calls also, at certain point, the *destroy* method of the *Misc* class, and there you can find also another documentation:

```
def destroy(self):
    """Internal function.
    Delete all Tcl commands created for
    this widget in the Tcl interpreter."""
```

Which does not say that also the Tcl interpreter is stopped (like in the *quit* method described above).

When constructing a Tk instance, a method called `_loadtk` is called. In this method, it is set the `protocol` when the Tk window is closed:

```
self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.destroy)
```

as you can see, `destroy` (and not *quit*) is associated with the closing event of the window.

---

This all means that when you close the window, the Tk instance and all its children are destroyed, but the Tcl interpreter is not stopped.

Answer (score 3):

`Tkinter.Tk` is the big poppa granddaddy of all tkinter windows. It runs the logic and communicates with the OS. When it goes -- they all go.